# discrepancy between for loop reading of file into list and order of elements in list

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I'm currently trying to read a spectrogram file from [here](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/features/track000.melspec). When i run the following code a list is populated with results from the file. However there is a discrepancy between all of the values printed on the line "%.12f" and elements that are printed out manually: case in point the correct initial value is 0.751491727533 and the for loop to print out all elements in the list starts with 0.003396112601. This is a really weird difference as the for loop seems to produce only gobbledy gook elements but the manual indexing of the array produces the correct elements. Its not a massive issue as i can apparently index the correct elements in order but it's left me tearing my hair out trying to figure why the behaviour is so different.

```
def skipToFrame(spectrogram, offset):
  SAMPLE_RATE =22050
  HOP_LENGTH = 512
  FRAME_TIME = HOP_LENGTH/SAMPLE_RATE
  SHIFT_FRAMES = round(offset/FRAME_TIME)

  a_list = []
  with open(spectrogram) as spectrogram_file:
      for line in spectrogram_file.readlines():
          for entry in line.split(" "):
              a_list.append(float(entry))
      spectrogram_file.close()

  for entry in a_list:
      print("%.12f" % entry)
  print("list length is " + str(len(a_list)))
  print(a_list[0])

def main():
  track_left_spectrogram = "path to file"
  skipToFrame(track_left_spectrogram,1)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  main()
```

The expected result should be that in the for entry in a_list loop the values in the a_list should be printed out in accordance with that of [this](http://aum.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/AlgoRhythms_Data/features/track000.melspec) file. Indexing the a_list manually gives apparently the correct results, but using a for loop ends up in elements that are perhaps out of order or just plain weird.

Comment: I tried your code and the first item printed in the for loop is 0.751491727533 maybe your console can't show them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
a_list = []
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        for entry in line.split(" "):
            a_list.append(entry)


for entry in a_list[:-2]:
    print("%.12f" % float(entry))
print("list length is " + str(len(a_list)))
print(a_list[0])
```

Output is

```
0.751491727533
2.798113439302
4.068138343604
17.569424700243
32.742568351020
23.357022526269
23.131132464710
9.801858358417
1.490128686136
0.034301546746
0.001143059877
0.000636652547
0.000168888218
0.000133326873
0.000084786511
0.000089979358
0.000030828024
0.000017362478
...
0.751491727533
```

Notice when you use `with` statement with open function, you do not need to close the file at the end, because with would automatically close it for you

Comment: [this](https://ibin.co/4oFAqyeJ2rXl.png) is what i'm getting - a bunch of results such as 669, 0.045132550796 instead of 0.751....

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to work fine, if you only print the first 10 it show the correct sequence. If you print all of them I think your terminal cannot show the 946176 lines so it cuts it off, as mine did.

```py
for entry in a_list[:10]:
    print("%.12f" % entry)
```

Comment: ok you seem to be onto something - if i do this then i get the elements in the right order.